# JPA Query to select whether a field has value or not, or both

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Pretty new with JPA Query

I am assigned to retrieve data from a postgresql database table, with three cases:

- either a certain field has value or not
- if a field has value
- if a field has not value

I use a Boolean requestparam that can either be `true`, `false` or `null` and use it to query from the repository

At first, I separated the repository queries but for performance reasons, I am tasked to use only one repository query, using the `@Query` annotation

I am trying to use `CASE WHEN` without much success, here is what I came up with so far

```java
@Query("SELECT e FROM Elements e"
+ " WHERE e.fieldOfInterest = "
+ " CASE WHEN :parameter IS NULL e.fieldOfInterest"
+ " WHEN :parameter = true THEN NOT NULL
+ " ELSE NULL END")
List<Elements> findWithNullableParam(@Param("parameter") Boolean parameter);
```

And I'm hit with the following error when compiling

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: NOT near line 1, column 161
```

I am aware that a `WHERE field = NOT NULL` will not be okay

I am considering using [NULLIF()](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_case_expressions) in my CASE block but I have no idea how it works yet

How do I formulate the query for my conditions to be met?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Queries in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193337/dynamic-queries-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: @pringi sadly no, it does not. In my question, it is just a sample code, but I have many other nullable parameters in my function, and the rest of them are working, only for that particular field, it's not working because of the three conditions

Comment: You problem is that you cannot use CASE statement for what you are trying to do. "NOT NULL" is not valid (is not a value). e.fieldOfInterest and NULL are values, so syntax in the first WHEN and in the ELSE are ok. I suggest you to rewrite without using case, using, for example, CriteriaBuilder or QueryDSL, or simplify the query by itself.